# Fetch MIN and MAX in the same row

Tags: mysql, max, min

Imagine a table called `training_route` which contains several rows each with a `rowId`, `gpsLocation` and a `athleteId` and consider the following:

- The lowest `rowId` defines the first location and the largest `rowId` defines the last location
- All rows together defines a route for the associated athlete to run

Ex.

```
rowId   athleteId   gpsLocation
100       1           "40.7127837,-74.00594130000002" <- first location for athlete #1
101       1           "41.1234872,-71.41300000022342"
102       1           "42.1234872,-69.23112200022342" <- last location for athlete #1
103       2           "39.5993499,-74.00594130000002" <- first location for athlete #2
104       2           "38.9093885,-73.31300000022342"
106       2           "37.1234872,-63.34215200022342" <- last location for athlete #2
107       3           ...
```

What I would like to have is the first and last location for each route grouped by the athleteId, in the very same row by the very same query:

```
athleteId   firstLocation                       lastLocation
1           "40.7127837,-74.00594130000002"     "42.1234872,-69.23112200022342"
2           "39.5993499,-74.00594130000002"     "37.1234872,-63.34215200022342"
3           ...             ...
```

How would that MySQL-query look like?

P.S.

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT training_route.athleteId,
       ( SELECT training_route.gpsLocation FROM training_route WHERE training_route.athleteId = route.athleteId ORDER BY training_route.rowId ASC  LIMIT 1 ) AS firstLocation,
       ( SELECT training_route.gpsLocation FROM training_route WHERE training_route.athleteId = route.athleteId ORDER BY training_route.rowId DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS lastLocation,
FROM   training_route AS route
WHERE  training_route.athleteId IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) GROUP BY training_route.athleteId;
```

But I'm ashamed that's the best I've come up with so far since it's totally unacceptable perfomance-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should work with mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
        SELECT MIN(rowid) minrowid
               , MAX(rowid) maxrowid
               , athleteid
        FROM  training_route
        GROUP BY
              athleteid
       ) minmax
       INNER JOIN training_route trmin ON trmin.athleteid = minmax.athleteid 
                                          AND trmin.minrowid = minmax.rowid
       INNER JOIN training_route trmax ON trmax.athleteid = minmax.athleteid 
                                          AND trmax.maxrowid = minmax.rowid
```

**The idea is to**

- get the min and max rowid's for each athlete
- join the previous results again with the table to get the gps coörodinates for the min rowid
- and join again with the original table to get the gps coörodinates for the max rowid

Comment: I tried something similar but did not even know you could do the "main query" in the from statement, that saved my night, thanks!

Comment: @Rikard - You're welcome. It's a good construct to remember because it works in most (if not all) DBMS's. It will sure come in handy later.